# Odd NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, vuze

After installing the latest version of Vuze (Azureus), I got an odd error trying to start it:

```
> java -Xmx128m -classpath ./Azureus2.jar:./swt.jar -Djava.library.path=/bt_work/vuze -Dazureus.install.path=/bt_work/vuze -Dazureus.script=./azureus -Dazureus.script.version=2 org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gudy/azureus2/ui/swt/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

What's odd is this:

```
> javap -classpath ./Azureus2.jar:./swt.jar org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final java.lang.String PR_MULTI_INSTANCE;
...
```

So ... running `javap` with the same classpath finds the class but `java` alone can't. WTF is going on?

I checked that both programs come from the same install Java (`/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun`), that's Java 6 and the classes were compiled for Java 5. The manifest isn't signed. The JAR file is readable (`unzip -t` reports no errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word: [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor)

In my case, the config didn't allow the program `java` to load the JARs from the new installation path.

If you have a similar problem, look into `/var/log/audit.log`. You should see the error messages there.

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` happens when the class itself is found but the class loader cannot load all the classes it needs.

Can you check the import headers for class `org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.java` and make sure that all the imported classes can be found in your classpath. If not, add the jar files to your classpath.

Post the import section if you want me to help figure out what is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and not exactly `ClassNotFoundException` - so `javap` will still be able to disassemble the class.

As you might know `NoClassDefFoundError` can be seen as a linkage error. I tend to guess that the runtime is missing some required class to execute `org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main`
I guess it requires more JARs on classpath.
So `org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main` is available (that is why javap works) but one of its dependency is not found during runtime.

Also running SWT sometimes requires `-Djava.library.path` set to `swt` library (looking at your SO reputation I guess you know this)

*Edit*
Here is a link to one [Azureus shell script](http://www.mail-archive.com/pld-cvs-commit@lists.pld-linux.org/msg29847.html), which lists more classpath JARs.